# How to see when my git repo was forked?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I recently noticed that one of my github repos has been forked. I can see the user who forked it under the 'Members' tab, but the graph shown under the 'Network' tab is completely linear, with no indication of the fork shown. Is there any way to determine on which date this repo was forked?

Comment: not sure, but maybe using github API (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#list-forks)

Comment: there's a "created_at" field, it can be what you are looking for

Comment: @pedrorijo91 Thanks, that gave me my answer. If you repost your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using github API (developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#list-forks)

there's a "created_at" field, it can be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

From the GitHub repository page if you go to

The Insights tab -> then click Network in the list

the 'Network Graph' appears to have a separate row for each repository.  You can scroll back and it will show one branching off to start the new row.

Inconvenient if there are many commits in the branch you are trying scroll back through to see the branch date.